# WP API Filter By Post Schema

Tags: json, wordpress, wp-api

Is it possible to return a list of posts based from the Wordpress Rest API v2 based on their schema:

For List of Schemas:
http://v2.wp-api.org/reference/posts/

I want to filter by sticky field, but the same would go for the rest of the fields.

So far I have:

```
/wp-json/wp/v2/posts?filter[sticky]=true
/wp-json/wp/v2/posts?filter[sticky]=1
```

Both return the same response as the standard endpoint:

```
/wp-json/wp/v2/posts
```

I have read other material such detailing how to sort by [meta](http://torquemag.io/2014/09/working-meta-data-using-json-rest-api/) or custom [taxonomies](http://torquemag.io/2014/10/working-taxonomies-using-json-rest-api/) but I don't believe that's the same as this.

Comment: It would appear [this is not implemented yet](https://github.com/WP-API/WP-API/issues/924)

Comment: Apparently it's supposed to be implemented via the `filter[ignore_sticky_posts]=true|false`, but that's not working for me in *Beta11*. Ongoing investigation here: https://github.com/WP-API/WP-API/issues/2210

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After going through the documentation and looking and posting issues on the WP-API Github repo, it's become clear that the `filter[ignore_sticky_posts]` should toggle the expected sorting behaviour, so that sticky posts are either always first (default) or ignored (by using `filter[ignore_sticky_posts]=true`).

However, there's [currently a bug in WP API](https://github.com/WP-API/WP-API/issues/2210#issuecomment-178230263) that makes the `filter[ignore_sticky_posts]` flag unusable.

The best way to fix it now would be to [create you own custom endpoint](http://v2.wp-api.org/extending/adding/) to get the data or IDs of all the sticky posts in your database. By looking at the code [discussed in this thread](https://wordpress.org/support/topic/sticky-posts-and-custom-loop?replies=9) and in [the WP-API documentation](http://v2.wp-api.org/extending/adding/), I think adding the following code to your `functions.php` should do the trick:

```
// Sticky posts in REST - https://github.com/WP-API/WP-API/issues/2210
function get_sticky_posts() {
    $posts = get_posts(
        array(
            'post__in' => get_option('sticky_posts')
        )
    );

    if (empty($posts)) {
        return null;
    }

    return $posts;
}
add_action( 'rest_api_init', function () {
    register_rest_route( 'THEME_NAME/v1', '/sticky', array(
        'methods' => 'GET',
        'callback' => 'get_sticky_posts',
    ));
});
```

If you `GET` **/wp-json/THEME_NAME/v1/sticky**, you should get an array of all your sticky posts.

I hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

In addition to Laust Deleuran's answer (thanks Laust!), i've created an altered version of his script which allows you to use the `embedded` feature of the `REST-api`.

Although this might not be 'the cleanest' solution, it does allow you to fully use the `wp-json`'s functionality.

```
function get_sticky_posts(WP_REST_Request $request) {

    $request['filter'] = [
        'post__in' => get_option('sticky_posts')
    ];

    $response = new WP_REST_Posts_Controller('post');
    $posts = $response->get_items($request);

    return $posts;
}

add_action( 'rest_api_init', function () {
    register_rest_route( 'THEME_NAME/v1', '/sticky', array(
        'methods' => 'GET',
        'callback' => 'get_sticky_posts',
    ));
});
```

This will output the sticky `posts` in the same `schema` as a normal `/wp-json/wp/v2/posts` query would respond.